# Conditional Formatting using SWITCH

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to conditionally format the a column that has percentages. The current formula I have doesn't work. How could I rewrite this in the efficient form using selected value and do i have to use var col instead? My error message says a single value for column SFTY cannot be determined :  :

```
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    'SF Data'[SFTY]>80.0,"#f07f94",
    'SF Data'[SFTY]>50.0,"#f7c979",
    'SF Data'[SFTY]<20.0,"#f07f94",
    "#f5f3f0"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a measure:
This is because you are using the column directly. When writing a measure, you should aggregate the columns. You should use `MAX('SF Data'[SFTY]), AVERAGE('SF Data'[SFTY]), SUM('SF Data'[SFTY])` depending on your needs.